# Fill DataGrid from a list of items

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

Actually, I have a small wpf application which have a DataGrid window that I could not fill it with objects.

In my ViewModel class I have this:

```
     public class UserViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public UserViewModel()
            {
                User myUser = new User();
            }
            ...

        }
```

Note that the Object myUser have 3 properties: ID, Name, and Notes which is a list containing other properties : NoteID, NoteTitle, NoteDescription.

```
<Window.DataContext>
        <local:UserViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <DataGrid Name="noteDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns >
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=NoteID}" Header="ID"/>

            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Title}" Header="Title"/>

            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Description}" Header="Desc"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

That's it, I know that there is something that does not match, but this is my first WPF (MVVM) Application, that's why i'll be so glad to have a solution.

Best Regards

Comment: There must be some collection which you must try to bind to Datagrid.Please post some more code of your View Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your VM you have to expose some collection, say, `List<User> Users`. Important: it *must* be a property.
2. Then just add items to this collection in your constructor.
3. Bind to the collection to `DataGrid` this way: `ItemsSource="{Binding Users}"`.
4. Voila.

Also, `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` will duplicate your columns (you add them both manually and automatically).

Comment: Thank you for your answer (which solved my problem), But I have an other question, if I do not add items to my list in the VM constructor, but in some other method later in the VM,  would that be possible ?

Comment: @Ali yes, but you have to use `ObservableCollection<User>` instead of `List`.